# Function, in MATLAB dna replication

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out the function command in Matlab and im having some difficulties.
I'm trying to write a Matlab function named dna_replicate. It will replicate a given strand and return its partner strand

For example if the user enters ATGCATGCAHGCAGTC, it should return TACGTACGT CGTCAG

A-->T
G-->C  if the user enters other than these 4 letters, there should be blank in the partner strand. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function out = dna_replicate(in)
in = upper(in); % Ensures all same case
A = in=='A';
T = in=='T';
C = in=='C';
G = in=='G';
out = in;
out(A) = 'T';
out(T) = 'A';
out(C) = 'G';
out(G) = 'C';
out(~(A|T|C|G)) = ' ';
```

while @Jirka cigler answer works, it uses a for loop as well as dynamically growing vector 'out'. As matlab is optimized for vector operations, this answer should perform better.

Comment: This works perfectly and i understood most of it except out(~(A|T|C|G)) = ' ';

Comment: @matlab padawan - It sets all non-ATGC elements to the space character. In logic, the index is (not(A or T or C or G)).

Comment: I should mention that @jasxun has the most efficient answer however. Good job!

Answer (score 7):

This implementation should be faster, involving only a simple table look-up. Note that the table `t` is constructed only **once** when the function is first called.

```
function out = dna_replicate(in)
  persistent t
  if isempty(t)
    t = blanks(256);
    t('ATGC') = 'TACG';
  end
  out = t(in);
end
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really nice solution. Also easily extensible to lower case.

Comment: Nice, but you can simplify the contents of the if statement to just these two lines: `t = blanks(256); t('ATGC') = 'TACG';`

Comment: Thanks @gnovice, your suggestion is so great that I had to incorporate it into the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple vectorized solution using the function [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

```
function outString = dna_replicate(inString)
  [~,index] = ismember(upper(inString),'ACGT');  %# Find the indices of inStrings
                                                 %#   letters in string `ACGT`
  outString = 'ACGT ';             %# Initialize outString to `ACGT` and a blank
  outString = outString(5-index);  %# Use inverted and shifted index to expand
                                   %#   outString to the size of inString
end
```

And here's a test:

```
>> dna_replicate('ATGCATGCAHGCAGTC')

ans =

TACGTACGT CGTCAG
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be implemented as follows:

```
   function out=dna_replicate(in)
for i=1:numel(in)
    switch in(i)
        case 'A'
            out(i)= 'T';
        case 'G'
            out(i)= 'C';
        case 'T'
            out(i)='A';
        case 'C'
            out(i)='G';
        otherwise
            out(i)=' ';
    end
end
```

this function has argument of type char

```
in='ATGCATGCAHGCAGTC'
```

and you can run

> > out=dna_replicate(in)

to get the same result as you want :-)